# Why Can't I Make This JS Script Work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    alert('hue');
});
```

And I have this element on my html:

```
<li>
   <a id="test" href="#contato">Contato</a>
</li>
```

And I have already imported my scrolling script and jQuery.js script.

```
<script src="js/scrolling.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

But when I click my  element, there's no alert()!
What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix this?

Comment: I really recommend to [**read the jQuery tutorial**](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). Also, read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can help yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean `js/scrolling.js` contains

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    alert('hue');
});
```

In that case, you will need to include `scrolling.js` after jQuery. And if those script tags are in the `<head>` of your html, you will need to wrap in a DOM-ready function, as you can't bind to an element before it exists on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").click(function() {
        alert('hue');
    });
});
```